# Have {reached / come / got} to class 6th

Tags: word-choice

My brother is not focusing on his study properly.

Which of the sentences I would say?

> You need to pay more attention as you have **reached** to class 6th.
>
> You need to pay more attention as you have **come** to class 6th.
>
> You need to pay more attention as you have **got** to class 6th.

Comment: will you please explain what "class 6th" mean in your sentence? The answers already use 3 different meanings, all of them possible.

Comment: Do you mean: your brother has managed to reach the 6th form in "high school"??

Comment: Brother was in class 5th and after passing the exam he is in 6th

Answer (score 4):

You need to pay more attention as you are now in class 6th.

In American English, we say 6th grade. Not sure that class 6th is right even in other varieties of English. In the UK, it's 6th form.

reach, come and got are too complicated for this idea.

as you have now **got to x,** also works. meaning: managed to get that far.

Answer (score 1):

OP clarified that "class 6th" = 6th year of school (6th grade):

> You need to pay more attention, as you have **got** to the **6th grade** now.

or:

> You need to pay more attention, since you are in the 6th grade now.

or:

> You need to pay more attention, since you are a 6th-grader now.

Comment: ranking is within a class, this is about getting to it.

Comment: @Lambie: I am not able to notice the errors in my suggestions. I will happily correct them, please help (you may edit the answer, I will study the correct sentences). Regarding "ranked", I already asked a question to the OP to clarify - "class 6th" can mean do many things.

Comment: This is simply not about ranking **in a class**. It is about getting to that level. Also, "dedicate yourself more to your studies" sounds like Italian, French, etc.

Comment: Well, there are too many possible meanings to "class 6th" - and yours is a valid one. How can I transform them to sound more English? As I mentioned before, I am not a native speaker. Note: I also tried to stay close to the original sentence.

Comment: If he had meant rank, he probably would have used the word position, not 6th class, which is a grade or form. It sounds like it means the guy is no longer in primary school.

Comment: This is more of a style choice than a grammatical fix, but I'd be inclined to say: _Now that you've reached sixth grade, you need to pay more attention._

Answer (score -2):

Get (in this context) refers to arriving, while come refers to leaving. So this depends on if your brother is going to his class or leaving his class.

Comment: No, "come" doesn't mean "leave".

Comment: Get has a meaning of “To go to” as in arriving, while come has a meaning of “To go from” as in leaving. I never said come meant leave.